Inadequate beam support
a bit of an urgent matter for us, appreciate any help. Our inspected noted inadequate beam support on the main support beam (pictured). The beam seemed to have shifted. Our inspector says we can reinforce it with a lally column but contractors who saw these same pictures said very different things. Some said just do lally poles, cost a few thousand. One said it's a much bigger issue and may need to go floor by floor to fix. Just want to get more opinions on this.
Pictures:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/3d64Y99v8Uq1xeJw7
https://photos.app.goo.gl/B2W1StG6dZBdG3219
https://photos.app.goo.gl/B2W1StG6dZBdG3219

I'm going to answer this by not answering it: you need a structural engineer onsite. Any of our advice is worth less than you paid for it.

According to what I see in the pictures, I do not have good news at all. The beam ends pictured where encased in the brickwork. The brick work holds moisture which in turn will rot the wood beam. This is what it looks like to me. I done a replacement like this, some years ago. Same situation.
The beam ends, since they were tightly encased in the brick, the only way the beam can move at all is if the ends are rotted. Depending on what and where the framing is that the beam is supporting, a lally column may or may not do task of resupporting the ends, then again, it may. If a lally column will work, there needs to be adequate support under where the column set on the floor. It cannot be just the floor slab only, it needs to have concrete footings under the column base as well.
Temporary support will need to be put in place while this work is done, that is if what I see in the pictures is accurate. The pictures only show the ends of the beam at the walls, I have no idea where the nearest posts are, if any. All that matters too.
